# PowerShell Prompt - Show User and System Path separately

Tags: powershell, path, environment-variables

I'm a new to PowerShell, so I need a help to optimize my code.
I'm trying to make it as short as possible.
If you paste this into PS Prompt:

```
"(USR PATH):" > env.txt;
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path','User').Split(';') >> env.txt;
[Environment]::NewLine >> env.txt;
"(SYS PATH):" >> env.txt;
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path','Machine').Split(';') >> env.txt;
[Environment]::NewLine >> env.txt
```

It will write apart '*User*' and '*System*' Path (environment variables)
to the text file in your current directory. **Any ideas to make it shorter**?

Actually, I like the single line variant, but unfortunately it will
concatenate '*User*' and '*System*' Path variables together.

```
$env:path -split ';'
```

**Note**: I have already tried to solve this problem with `cmd.exe`.

```
path > env.txt
```

Simple and short command, but it outputs a single `Path` string without any splitting (;) and makes no distinction between `User Path` and `System Path`. Why? Because `cmd.exe` is very old-time tool. Actually PATH was originally a single variable going back in DOS days. However, once Windows became a multi-user OS, there was a need to provide users their own PATH setting as well there are a system-wide settings. So the only way to separate the user variable from the system variable is by using registry keys, which is excessively complex.

Now I'm trying to solve this with **PowerShell v1.0**. It seems like this is a very old version. So *backtick* (grave accent) and *pipeline* operators don't work for me. I can't even keep up with **68 characters per line**. For example, this line break code doesn't work for some reasons:

```
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path','User').Split(';') `
>> env.txt;
[Environment]::NewLine >> env.txt;
```

There are also many of repetitive fragments, like `>> env.txt`, which can be optimized if you first save the output somewhere. But my knowledge is not enough to do this.

Comment: Why does it have to be short? Wouldn't it be better to do what you need?  ;-) I'd recommend to use either two separate files or another file type like CSV or XML or PSD1 ...

Comment: It has to be short because it does a trivial thing. By 'short' I mean PS code not the output. Indeed Linux style of doing such things is very laconic compared to the Microsoft.

Comment: PowerShell code is by design much more verbose and easily readable even for less experienced coders.  What is it actually what you want to do? What do you do with the file `env.txt`?

Comment: @Olaf File is just a simple and convenient way to check environment.

Comment: What is the goal/purpose? Management of the `Path` variable?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart The goal is to **Shift + Right click** on the Desktop,  Open _Command Prompt_ and paste or type a short code. Then you'll have a file on your Desktop with your `Path` Environment in human readable format.

Comment: Why not just run `rundll32 sysdm.cpl EditEnvironmentVariables` and get variables in a nice GUI?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart nice one line GUI on Windows 7 when the entire list of paths must fits into a 38-character field? Are you kidding? You probably have Windows 10 on your PC. Perhaps things are better there, but it's not for sure.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Besides I need the universal solution when GUI is not an option.

Comment: (Aside: Windows 7 is no longer supported) As an alternative, maybe try [EditPath.exe](https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PathMgr/releases), and just type `editpath -sl;"";editpath -ul` at a PowerShell prompt. ([Documentation for EditPath tool](https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PathMgr/blob/master/EditPath.md))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution which should work with any version of PoSH, on any Windows OS (since Win 7) and without the need to download third-party programs. This quite enough compact and universal:

- `Shift` + `Right click` on the Desktop
- Open Command Prompt through popup menu
- Type `powershell` command
- Paste code snippet into console.

Then you'll have a file with your `PATH` Environment.

```
$n = "`r`n"; $u = "(USR-PATH): $n$n"; $s = "(SYS-PATH): $n$n";
$usr = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path','User');
$sys = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path','Machine');
$u + $usr + $n + $n + $s + $sys + $n -split ';' > env.txt
```

Also you can add the following line to the previous snippet to get all Environment variables:

```
ls env: >> env.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, PowerShell works best when you work with objects and pipelines primarily deferring string formatting until absolutely necessary

Often, this leads to *longer* code, but simpler to read, debug, and maintain over time.

```
@('Machine', 'User', 'Process') |
  ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
      Scope=$_
      Paths=[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $_) -split ';'
    }
  } |
  ForEach-Object {
    Write-Output "$($_.Scope): $($_.Paths -join "`n")"
  } | Set-Content -Path 'env.txt'
```

Why I like this code:

- Easy to customize which scopes to include (notice I included `Process` for completeness, but this is easy to remove if undesired)
- Developed iteratively: I didn't start with the full thing, just the array and first loop.  Once it produces the right shape, I added the second loop to convert the complex object into simple output
- `Set-Content` can be omitted while developing so you are just
  iterating on the console (nothing beats the "up arrow" feedback loop!)
- Don't have to deal with file semantics -- works if the file exists or not, doesn't require a specific order of operations, etc

What I don't like:

- It is very verbose

Comment: Actually this looks good for the whole PS-Script. Not just something that you can simply paste in your _Command Prompt_. Besides as far as I know this will not work with old **PowerShell v1.0**

Comment: Why do you need support for PowerShell v1?

Comment: "Not just something that you can simply paste in your Command Prompt" --

That's the beauty of it, you can!
PowerShell can be run in an IDE, via a script, or just pasting into a terminal.

Comment: The powershell 1 requirement is new since the original post.

That severely limits the possible solutions

Comment: @Bill_Stewart "Why do you need support for PowerShell v1" Maybe because it's preinstalled out of the box in Win7? So if you have a solution for v1, - you have universal solution for Win 7-10-11? And you don't need to download anything for each trivial task.

Comment: Incorrect; PowerShell "out of the box" on Windows 7 is PowerShell 2.0 (run `$PSVersionTable` to see for yourself).

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is a good idea it will be much harder to read, but I think it is shorter.

```
@(1,'USR'),@(2,'SYS')|%{("("+$_[1]+" PATH):");[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH',$_[0]).Split(';');""} > env.txt
```

Comment: This looks like a suitable variant. Unfortunately it doesn't work for old version of PowerShell v1.0. Also, It would be just a great if each line could fit in 68 characters. But this is already quite the ultimate dream.

Answer (score 0):

One possible alternative is to get EditPath.exe from my GitHub page:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PathMgr/blob/master/EditPath.md

Copy EditPath.exe to a directory in your Path, and then enter the following command at the PowerShell prompt:

```
PS C:\> editpath -sl;"";editpath -ul
```

This will output the directories in the system path, a blank line, then the directories in the user path. If you want the program to expand the %environment variable% references in the string, add `x` to the parameter; e.g.:

```
PS C:\> editpath -slx;"";editpath -ulx
```

The documentation (link above) also explains how to use EditPath.exe to make changes to the system and/or user path.